# Using Regex to get the value in a HTML tag?

Tags: php, regex, tags

I'm using this regex code to get the tags but *not* the value:

```
(<input type="hidden" name="pt" id="pt" value=")|(" \/>)
```

From this code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pt" id="pt" value="f64b1aadf7baa6e416dbfb6bf95fa031" />
```

But how would I do it the other way around? Get the value, but not the surrounding tags? So I would only get "f64b1aadf7baa6e416dbfb6bf95fa031" (without the quotes). Thanks.

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML, etc.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What language? All use regexes a bit differently.

Comment: Try `value = "f64b1aadf7baa6e416dbfb6bf95fa031"`. You have to be more specific about which situations your solution should work for -- all valid HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Donut says, you seriously shouldn't use regexes on HTML. However, since this is a pretty straightforward case I'll be an enabler. But seriously, if it gets one iota more complicated, switch to a DOM parser.

```
value="(.+?)"
```

I'm assuming you are using PHP, so to get the captured group out, do this:

```
preg_match('value="(.+?)"', $input, $groups);
echo "Value = " . $groups[1];
```

The `?` makes it a lazy operator, so it grabs up to the first quotation mark. If there is the possibility of escaped quotation marks inside the quotation marks you need to add this:

```
value="(.+?[^\\])"
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is generally not advisable to attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, you could try this: `value="([^"]*)"`.